# Levi-Civita connection preserves Hodge star eigenspace decomposition

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

For an oriented Riemannian 4-manifold, we have the Levi-Civita connection associated natually to the metric. This connection also gives us a linear connection on all tensor fields over the manifold, especially for two forms.

We have w.r.t. this metric, the decomposition of space of two forms into +1 and -1 eignespaces of Hodge star operator.

My question is, how can we prove that the Levi-Civita connection preserves this decomposition? i.e. for any tangent field $X$, if $\omega$ is a self-dual 2-form, do we also have that the $\nabla_X\omega$ is also a self-dual 2-form?

Is there any easier way to see this?

Comment: Easier than what?

Comment: Can you show that $\nabla_X$ commutes with $\star$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996515/272127